# Sql return all sibling result

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I need some help to do some query. I will be given 2 parameter (`@dateFrom`, `@dateTo`). Basically the relationship of `tblRequest` to `tblLog` is one-to-many. I'm trying to query based on LogDate. Say I need to query date from 2015/02/01 - 2015/02/28, my current query will return one row result from tblLog. But referring to this scenario, instead return 1 result, I need to return all of its sibling's (same RequestId, which 3 row).

```
select * from tblRequest
inner join tblLog on tblLog.RequestId = tblRequest.Id
where Logdate >= @dateFrom and Logdate < @dateto
```

Anybody know how can I achieve this? I'm using MS Sql.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL, and date/time funtionality is often product specific...)

Comment: Given your date range it will only return one result as you only have 1 row in tbllog that has this date range

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. But I would like it to return all of its sibling (even the condition is not met).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your logic is correct, then you need an additional `join` or condition to bring in all the similar request ids.  Here is an example using `in`:

```
select r.name, l.*
from tblRequest r inner join
     tblLog l
     on l.RequestId = r.Id
where r.id in (select l2.RequestId
               from tblLog l2
               where l2.Logdate >= @dateFrom and l2.Logdate < @dateto
              );
```

As a note, you could also approach this with window functions:

```
select rl.*
from (select r.name, l.*,
             sum(case when l.LogDate >= @dateFrom and l.Logdate < @dateto
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by r.id) as cnt
      from tblRequest r inner join
           tblLog l
           on l.RequestId = r.Id
     ) rl
where cnt > 0;
```

Two different ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way that SQL works, your above scenario will only return 1 row as it is in the only one in that date range, maybe just try:

```
select * from tblRequest
inner join tblLog on tblLog.RequestId = tblRequest.Id
where Logdate < @dateto
```

This will return all results for that Request